# como por imagem para redimensionar em FullScreen PyQt5

Tags: pyqt-5

Estou iniciando como TI e achei essa biblioteca perfeita que é a pyqt5, porem tem algumas coisas que eu não consigo fazer totalmente porque o método que eu a uso parece que não funciona. Ao invés de eu criar uma tela apenas por código, ou criar no QTdesigner e passar ela para Python, eu uso os dois ao mesmo tempo, eu vou editando no QTdesigner e importo por "uic.LoadUi()". eu queria por uma imagem como Background numa tela cheia, porem quando eu coloco a imagem no centralwidget, ou ela fica muito grande, ou ela é cortada, além de ela não ficar apenas como papel de parede e sim para todas as cosias que eu colocar lá, uma label, uma QlineEdit etc. como posso fazer ela se redimensionar sozinha para tela cheia de um PC e não ficar em todos os objetos?

um exemplo teste:

```
from PyQt5 import uic,QtWidgets
#app
app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
Tela_qualquer = uic.loadUi('teste.ui')
Tela_qualquer.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(df.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center")
Tela_qualquer.show()
app.exec()
```

A tela com um botão e uma Qlabel e a foto cortada:
[image: Imagem cortada com botão e Qlabel borrado]

A imagem inteira:
[image: A imagem inteira]

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tens que colocar outro layout que fica por cima do central_widget, e é nesse layout que colocas os componentes.
Primeiro colocas a imagem de fundo no central_widget:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class TelaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TelaPrincipal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tela Principal')
        self.setGeometry(100, 200, 600, 300)
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 300)

        image_path = r'df.jpg'

        # label para colocar a imagem
        central_widget = QLabel()

        pix_map = QPixmap()
        pix_map.load(image_path)
        central_widget.setPixmap(pix_map)

        # redimensionar a imagem
        central_widget.setScaledContents(True)

        # usar o label como central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # criar o layout do central widget para colocar outros widgets por cima
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
```

Em seguida colocas um widget por cima onde leva os componentes:

```
        # criar o widget e o respectivo layout para receber os componentes
        widget_1 = QWidget()
        widget_1_layout = QVBoxLayout(widget_1)

        # criar os componentes
        label_1 = QLabel('label 1')
        label_1.setStyleSheet('color: red')

        label_2 = QLabel('label 2')
        label_2.setStyleSheet('color: red')

        btn_1 = QPushButton('btn 1')
        btn_2 = QPushButton('btn 2')

        # colocar o widget_1 no layout do central widget
        self.layout.addWidget(widget_1)

        # colocar os componentes no layout do widget_1
        widget_1_layout.addWidget(label_1)
        widget_1_layout.addWidget(btn_1)
        widget_1_layout.addWidget(label_2)
        widget_1_layout.addWidget(btn_2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = TelaPrincipal()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```